# Responsive iframes for mobile phones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm having quite a bit of a problem in making my iframes work in mobile devices. It's only covering about a half or more of the screen. I suspect it is because of some lines of css I put in my iframes.

```
.Wrapper2 {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.Wrapper2 iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I would also like to add that for my text, I am using viewport sizing(vw, vh, vmin, vmax) if that would be of any help as I am also getting problems with long blocks of texts producing scrollbars. I also think (???) that it may have to do something with my iframe css and/or text sizing. What would be the necessary change that I need to implement? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could provide a fiddle demonstrating the problem because there isn't enough code here, but if I had to take a guess, I'd say maybe set a `display` type on your selectors and/or set a `width` on your `.Wrapper2`, but like I said, without seeing more code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your html to make it easier for us to understand what the problem is.

Try this -- If you look into your iframe in html then you'll find :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HDI9inno86U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So, there's width & height already defined inside the iframe element. All you have to do i change it to `width="100%"`;

Comment: This isn't necessarily the case.